# PHP: return the difference in Hours & Minutes between midnight today 00:00, and now

Tags: php

I am trying to return the difference in hours and minutes between midnight today "00:00" and now time.

Ths is what I have so far:

```
$now = date('H:i:s', time());
$time1 = strtotime('00:00:00');
$time2 = strtotime($now);
$difference = round(abs($time2 - $time1) / 3600,2);
echo $difference;
```

The returned value does not look correct, say the time now is 10:37, the returned difference is displaying as 10:63. Now thats not correct. Can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Cheers.

Comment: Might wanne go deeper into [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and even more specific the [date_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and design your output time.

```
$start_time = "00:00:00";
$end_time = date("H:i:s", time());

$time1 = new DateTime($start_time);
$time2 = new DateTime($end_time);
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

var_dump($interval); //for details about the interval times

echo $hour = $interval->format('%h hour'); // hour
echo $min = $interval->format('%i min');   // min
echo $sec = $interval->format('%s second');// sec
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be your answer

```
$start_time = "00:00";
$end_time = date("H:i");

$time1 = new DateTime($start_time);
$time2 = new DateTime($end_time);
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);

echo $hour = $interval->format('%h hour');
echo '<br/>';
echo $min = $interval->format('%i min');
```

Output is

15 hour

24 min

Output will vary when you run this code.I just pasted it from my machine.

Comment: Hi, Last question, how would I then convert the hours and minutes in to minutes?

Comment: You can multiply hours with 60 and add minutes. $hour *60 + $min . Will give you the result in minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this short snippet

```
$now = new DateTime(date('H:i:s'));
$midnight = new DateTime(date('00:00:00'));
$interval = $now->diff($midnight);
$result = $interval->format("%H hour(s) and %i minute(s)");
```